# Android implement "1 Tap Boost" as one in

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I have seen some apps that can start in special way, like this one:

[image]

When I tap to the icon, there is some animation (the icon become bigger, then a loading effect, then a message, etc...)

From the beginning I only know make an app that starts by opening an activity (a fullscreen app).

I tried to search this on Google but I have no idea what keyword would I use.

I want to ask how to make an app like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an app like this by using `Service` class which runs in the background. This is an app widget, so you need to learn about this in android app widgets section: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html